# String with date not able to load to MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I have a string which was converted from an array. The string that date fields and i keep getting error trying to load the dates into the table MS SQL

```
var str = hello,how,are,you,doing,today,2006-11-23 16:01:47
```

I inserting into a MS SQL table using sequelize

```
Let query = insert into value(${str});
sequelize.query(query).
```

Fails with

> Incorrect syntax near '16'.

So its somewhere near the time format starts.
I would like to insert the format as is
the `column` in the database is set to `VARCHAR(255)`

Comment: store dates as datetime, not strings. Much easier as you don't have to worry about formats (assuming you're using date variables in your code, and parameters to write your query), and you can do things in your queries like order them by date properly, add/subtract time from them, make comparisons to other dates, output in a different format etc. All of which is much harder with a string representation of a date

Comment: When you run your sequelize statement with a profiler trace on, what actual SQL statement does the profiler show is getting sent to the SQL Server?

Comment: I was able to load it by replacing all the values inside a single quotes.